# jQuery: re-arranging list items using eq

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, html-lists

I'm working on a navigation bar with 3 items. When you click an item, the item order should re-arrange so the clicked item is at the center (horizontal navbar). Here's the code so far:

```
$('li').mousedown(function(e){
    $('li').addClass('flanking');
    $(this).removeClass('flanking');

    $('ul li:eq(0)').after($(this));

    if( $(this) == '(ul li:eq(0)' ){
        $('ul li:eq(2)').prependTo('ul');
    };
});
```

This works for re-arranging the second and last place list items of the three, but not if you click the first. I've tried changing the if statement (intended to catch if the first item in the list is clicked) to the following

```
if( $(this) == $('ul li:eq(0)') ){
    $('ul li:eq(2)').prependTo('ul');
};
```

Which doesn't work either. How can I check if the clicked 'li' is the first in the 'ul', and then move it to the middle? Thanks for reading.

EDIT: See Jaak Kütt's answer for a scalable solution and working demo, Gokhan Arik's using eq and to the correct syntax for the if statement, and Birrel's for some pretty awesome animation.

Comment: are there always only 3 items or does this vary?

Comment: There are only 3 items

Comment: The item in center will have no class and other items will have `flanking` am I right?

Comment: Yes, the clicked list item will not have the 'flanking' class. Hmmmm I think I might see where you're going with this...

Comment: Wait no that was just the caffeine talking. Although I did try the following: var $first = $('li').first();
$first.insertAfter('ul li:eq(0)');

Which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `if` statement to this,

```
if( $(this)[0] == $('ul li:eq(0)')[0] ){
        $('ul li:eq(2)').prependTo('ul');
};
```

You are making mistake when you compare things. **jQuery** selector returns array of objects.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Came up with a more generic solution which doesn't care about how many elements are in the list and places the clicked element in the middle (or closest to the center if there is an even number of elements) while pushing the elements between the from-to points in the direction (top-bottom) it came from.

[This jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jaakkytt/97KAa/) features 4 different-length lists (in `<li>` and `<p>` sibling examples) and less line breaks.

```
$('li').mousedown(function (e) {
    var self = $(this),
        length = self.siblings().length + 1,
        middle = length / 2 - 1,
        list = self.parent().children(),
        i = self.index() - 1;
    if (length % 2) {
        $()[i < middle ? 'after' : 'before'].call(
            list.eq(Math.round(middle)), 
            self
        );
    } else {
        list.eq(
            Math[i < middle ? 'ceil' : 'floor'].call(null, middle)
        ).after(self);
    }
});
```

PS1: removed the "flanking" class business OP had from the example as it was not really relevant to the rest of the functuality.

PS2: any efforts to fine-tune the algebra involved will have my thanks :D

Comment: glad to help, tho suggest accpeting Gokhan Arik's answer because he actually used the eq() as suggested in your question

Comment: Thumbs up for Jaak, good answer. I just wanted to fix his code, your solution is good too.

Comment: @Ber was aiming for a solution which targets multiple lists, added an extra to the fiddle XD

Comment: @Ber check out this new generic upgrade which also features eq() :D

Comment: @Ber you could also combine this solution with the pretty animated one below ;).  Jaak knows his code, for sure!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3sqE2/5/) is one with animation, works properly now in Chrome.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li class="flank_left">1</li>
        <li class="middle">2</li>
        <li class="flank_right">3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 310px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 25 px;
    background: #099;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
.flank_left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.flank_right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 210px;
}
.middle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 105px;

}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('li').click(function () {
    // If not middle element and if not animated...
    if (!$(this).hasClass('middle') && !$('.middle').is(':animated')) { 

        if($(this).hasClass("flank_left") ){ // If flank_left
            $( this ).switchClass( "flank_left", "middle", 1000);
            $( '.middle' ).switchClass( "middle", "flank_left", 1000);
        }else{ // if flank_right
            $( this ).switchClass( "flank_right", "middle", 1000);
            $( '.middle' ).switchClass( "middle", "flank_right", 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

NOTE: There are *TWO* external resources that you need for this.  You can find them and download them [here](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js) and [here](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css)

Comment: Adding the external resources is as easy as including them in the header of your HTML.

Comment: Was just thinking, it works better to add `&& !$('.middle').is(':animated')` to the first `if` statement.  Otherwise the user can click on a different element while the animation is happening and things get all sorts of messed up.  Modified (and better) fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3sqE2/2/).

Comment: the fiddle demo in chrome 32.0.1700.76, the transition when clicking on the 3rd element seems to go less smoothly than with the first - the 3rd element jumps to left:0 and when reaches the second position, the second jumps to the third.. are you also seeing the result as that? :D

Comment: Interesting, I do.  I didn't test it in Chrome before.  What a bummer.  Standby for solution...

Comment: @JaakKütt for `.flank_right' CSS, change to `left: 210px; right: auto;` and all works as planned.  Fiddle with all updates [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3sqE2/4/).  Basically, space them all according to the desired width and padding, using the `left` CSS property.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: hey no problem - but I do suggest editing your answer to include the updated fiddle at the top as it's the first link the readers are going to click and there is not much point of keeping the a buggy example there :D

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented a re-arranging of list items with animation. The requirement was that I have five elements:

```
1   2   3   4   5
```

and rearrange order like, when click on 1st element it place the position in center like this:

```
5   4   1   2  3
```

you can check my fiddle: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozLqk4tr/4/)

```js
$('.horizontal li').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    var tparent = $(this).parent();
    var childs = tparent.children().length;
    var eachWidth = this.clientWidth + 10;
    var middle = eachWidth * (parseInt(childs / 2));
    var rowChild = $(this).parent().children('li');
    var currentIndex = rowChild.index($(this));

    rowChild.each(function (li) {
        if ($(this).attr("POS")) {
            cp = $(this).attr("POS");
        } else {
            $(this).attr("POS", li);
        }
    });

    function animateEach() {
        rowChild.each(function (li) {
            var _minePos = $(this).position().left;
            var cp = $(this).attr("POS");
            var _newPos = cp * eachWidth;

            $(this).animate({
                left: (cp - li) * eachWidth,
            }, 40, function () {
                // checkPOS();
            });
        });
        setTimeout(checkPOS(true), 40);
    }

    var currentelement = $(this);
    var currentIIN = $(this).attr("POS");

    function checkPOS(ee) {
        if (currentIIN != 2) {
            rowChild.each(function (li) {
                var eachPOS = $(this).attr("POS");
                if (eachPOS >= 4) {
                    $(this).attr("POS", 0);
                } else {
                    $(this).attr("POS", parseInt(eachPOS) + 1);
                }
            });
            currentIIN = currentelement.attr("POS");
            animateEach();
        } else {
            if (ee) currentelement.addClass('active');

        }
    }

    checkPOS();
```

```css
p {
    margin: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.horizontal {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}
ul.horizontal li {
    float: left;
    /*background: #ccc;*/
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.ul.horizontal .li.a {
    border:2px solid #fb7d1e;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.horizontal li.active {
    /*background:silver;*/
    font-weight:bold;
    color:blueviolet;
    font-size: 20px;
    /*height: 150px;*/
    /*width:150px;*/
    webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    /*border:1px solid ;*/
    /*border-radius: 1em;*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
    box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
}
/*background: #ccc;*/
 display: block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 position: relative;

}
.ul.horizontal .li.a {
    border:2px solid #fb7d1e;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.horizontal li.active {
    /*background:silver;*/
    font-weight:bold;
    color:blueviolet;
    font-size: 20px;
    /*height: 150px;*/
    /*width:150px;*/
    webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    /*border:1px solid ;*/
    /*border-radius: 1em;*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
    box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
}
```

Check my [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozLqk4tr/4/)

Comment: Don't ask questions as an answer